# What are the various Raw Materials that are needed to make Solid State Laser?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, laser

Industries have been using Solid State Lasers for quite a long period of time

I was going through this piece published by Honeywell where they talk about designing Solid State Laser. In this piece they wrote

[Raw Materials](http://www.madehow.com/Volume-6/Solid-State-Laser.html)

> Optical, mechanical, and electronic components made of various
>   materials (crystals, metals, semiconductors, etc.) are usually
>   supplied by other manufacturers. Outsourcing varies from laser
>   manufacturer to manufacturer. A solid state laser consists of two
>   major components, or "boxes." One component contains the optics
>   (lasing crystal and mirrors), and the other contains the electronics
>   (power supply, internal controls). Sometimes these two components are
>   integrated into one box.

However, they do not state what are the various Raw Materials that are needed to make Solid State Lasers. Obviously there are several types of chemicals & materials that are used.

So what are the various raw materials used in making solid state laser? Are there any authoritative source/s from where I can find out?

Comment: Originally ruby, now semiconductor diodes and Nd-YAG. Optics may contain non-linear crystals, like LiNbO3, for frequency doubling.

Comment: @Pieter Will you please state what are the various semi conductor diodes that are generally used?

Comment: Basically the same materials as for LEDs: various III-V semiconductors: GaAs/AlGaAs in the infrared, materials with larger bandgaps for shorter wavelengths.